# Hudson plugin to extract code and publish it to HTML

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We have a Hudson build server, and I have a fairly simple need. I'm wondering if a plugin exists for this, or if I should try to write one.

Basically, whenever a build occurs, I'd like to extract some C++ code and use it to produce an HTML table inside of an HTML file. The code specifically is a static array of structs like so:

```
typedef struct definition {
  int val;
  const char* name;
  const char* desc;
} DEFINITION;

static const DEFINITION def[] =
{
  {1, "abc", "def"},
  {3, "ghi", "jkl"},
  {5, "mno", "pqr"}
};
```

I'd like to extract the strings from the array and convert them into a two column HTML table. The code to write this would obviously be simple. I'm just new to Hudson and am not sure what the best approach is.

We already use Doxygen, but I'm not sure whether it can perform this job.

Comment: A plugin should be your last report.  One alternative is to have a program run that does this as a second build step in your builds.  Do you have any constraints that make this infeasible?

Comment: Thanks. You're right: this would probably be a lot simpler than a plugin, right? I'm new to the Hudson environment and thus not sure what the recommended approach is...if it's as simple as a script or executable that gets run as a build step, that sounds perfect.

Comment: Right.  A build step is a UNIX script or C program or Doxygen call or whatever you want it to be! And you set it up through the UI.